# How to migrate webform submissions data from one drupal to another

Tags: drupal-7, data-migration, drupal-webform, drupal-form-submission

Hello, I wonder if there is any way to migrate the records of a Webform (data submissions) of a site in Drupal 7 to a previous copy of the same site.

My form includes text fields, images and files, and am aware that the records of the form are not nodes.

For this reason, modules as 'Node Export' do not work (although I tried anyway).

Could anyone guide me to find the solution?

Or give me a place to start?

Answer (score 1):

Have you given [Migrate Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_webform) a try yet?

From the project page

> It will migrate all nodes of the webform node type (with the default
>   D6 fields using migrate_d2d backend), all the configuration* of the
>   webform's settings, the form components, email destinations,
>   submissions and **associated submission data**, in addition to any
>   validation configuration you have (from webform_validation module). It
>   grabs the "last downloaded" data too, in case your users were
>   downloading sequential batches since the last time they were on the
>   site.

Comment: I'll try that module and publish my results, thanks. =)

Comment: @EmmauelGarcía: How did you get on with Migrate Webform?

Comment: @Hugo: I couldn´t make it work in those days, so we ended up copying from the database. Well, in that case we only had a few records.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Webform Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_import).

> Allows delimited data files to be imported as submission (results)
>   into webforms.
>
> This is useful for importing submissions from other systems in to
>   Webform. Can also be used to Edit submissions via Export / Import as
>   long as the CSV has the SID column filled.

Comment: He will export/import the images and documents ...
But if you get some problems That because of the FID ( file id ) in the database so make sure to check the fid before you export you will find it in Table 'File_managed' and 'File_usage' if its the same no need to worry.
and you can copy/past the files if you want.